# Bootstrap Popover with Ajax call not showing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to update the popovers contents with Ajax result.

**ASP.Net (MVC4):**

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(string employeeId)
        {
            var contract = UnitOfWork.ContractRepository.ContractBusinessManager.GetContract(int.Parse(employeeId), DateTime.Now);

            return PartialView("_EmployeeDetails", contract);
        }
```

**Html:**

```
<a data-toggle-popup-employee-id="@evaluation.EmployeeId" >@evaluation.Employee.FullName.ToTitle()</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle-popup-employee-id]').popover(
        {
            html: true,
            placement: 'top',
            title: 'Title',
            container: 'body',
            content: function () {
                //$(this).off('hover');
                var employeeId = $(this).data('toggle-popup-employee-id');
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Evaluation")',
                    data: { employeeId: employeeId },
                    success: function (result) {
                        return result;
                        //var html = result;
                        //$(this).contents.html = result;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                })
            },
            trigger: 'hover'
        });
});
```

The call works fine and gives back the partial result as html but the popovers content is still empty...

**UPDATE:**

It appears that every time I hover over the link, 10 `[Object, HTMLAnchorElement]`
are added directly to the `$('[data-toggle-popup-employee-id]')`.
Each object has `InnerText` and `InnerHtml` set to the employees name...?

Comment: sample ajax result data looks like this
"    <div class=\"row\">\r\n        <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-6\">\r\n            <label>Name</label>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-6\">\r\n            ..."

Comment: I guess issue is with the result you r getting form ajax call popover methods looks fine

Comment: Hi, I'm looking into encoding/parsing the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd personally do something like the following...

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('[data-toggle-popup-employee-id]').on({
        mouseenter: function () {

            var originator = $(this);

            var employeeId = originator.data('toggle-popup-employee-id');

            $.get('@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Evaluation")', { employeeId: employeeId }, function (data) {

                originator.popover({
                    html: true,
                    placement: 'top',
                    title: 'Title',
                    container: 'body',
                    content: data,
                }).popover('show');

            })

        },
        mouseleave: function () {

            //
            // Destroy so the data will referesh
            //
            $(this).popover('destroy');

        }
    });

});
```

This way we are initialising the popover in the callback of the ajax request.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you heymega.

Comment: Out of all the answers on all the posts I could find on this subject, this was definitely the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.popover.in .popover-inner').html(data);
```